# Stack Overflow Error: Using constructors in base class and extended class?

Tags: java, class, recursion, constructor, stack-overflow

I'm pretty new to Java but I'm trying to fix this stack overflow error. Essentially, I'm trying to create a deck of cards using a constructor call in main: `Deck newDeck = new Deck();`

Then, creating the Cards array of 52 elements (cards) in the base class "Deck", and populating the array at each index with two `int` values, representing the rank and suit of each card.

I believe the stack overflow error is occurring due to a recursive constructor call between the base class and extended class, though I might be wrong. Can anyone provide a suggestion on how to fix this error, or populate the Cards array in a different way? The base class and extended class format is necessary for my project. Thanks.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.util.Random.<init>(Random.java:105)
at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:12)
at Cards.<init>(Cards.java:19)
at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:27)
at Cards.<init>(Cards.java:19)
at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:27)
at Cards.<init>(Cards.java:19)
at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:27)
at Cards.<init>(Cards.java:19)
at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:27)
at Cards.<init>(Cards.java:19)
```

Main:

```
 import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PokerProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // CREATING SCANNER OBJECT
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();

        // INITIALIZING VARIABLES
        String play = "y";
        double blind = 10;
        double playerBalance = 1000;
        double playerBet;
        double pot;
        int playerScore = 0;
        int compScore = 0;
        String[] Hands = {"Equal hand", "One Pair", "Two Pair", "Three of a Kind", "Straight", "Flush", "Full House", "Four of a Kind", "Straight Flush", "Royal Flush"};
        Deck newDeck = new Deck();
```

Base class:

```
 import java.util.Random;
    
    public class Deck{
        // Creating Random object
        Random random = new Random();
    
        // FIELD VARIABLES
    
        public static int handScore;
        public static int cardValue;
        private static final Cards[] newDeck = new Cards[52];
    
        // CONSTRUCTORS
    
        // For Deck
        public Deck () {
            int i = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    newDeck[i] = new Cards(j, k);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Extended Class :

```
public class Cards extends Deck{

// Field Variables
private int rank;
private int suit;

// Rank and Suit Arrays
private static String [] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
private static String [] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

// CONSTRUCTOR
public Cards (int rank, int suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

Comment: Never use a subclass in a superclass.

Comment: The `Cards` class extends `Deck` so every time you create a `Cards` you are also creating a `Deck`, which creates the `Cards`, etc.

Comment: So it is recursive. Thank you!

Comment: While the other answers/comments say _what_ is wrong, this doesn't say _why_ it's wrong or how to resolve it.  Here, your `Cards` class represents a _single_ `Card` (has rank and suit).  If you name it `Card` then the logic becomes simpler.  A `Card` is not an extension of a `Deck` (nor is a `Deck` an extension of a `Card`).  A `Deck` _has_ some `Cards`.  So there's no `extends` wanted in your class hierarchy here.

Answer (score 0):

Cards extend Deck. Upon creating a Deck you invoke the Cards constructor which happen to be a Deck which invokes the Cards constructor...